# why is my android:layout_weight not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have created a dummy `View`  and filled it with weight=1

I want all the extra space to go to that view, but it doesn't happen in reality.

what am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
                    android:id="@+id/whyResgisterHeaderText"
                    style="@style/textOnBg"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="WHY REGISTER?"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:font_type="varela" />

                <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
                    android:id="@+id/whyResgisterBodyText"
                    style="@style/textOnBg"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:text="first line\nsecond line\nthird line\nforth line"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_why" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gotItAction"
                    android:layout_width="283dp"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
                        android:id="@+id/goItText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Got it"
                        android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: weight doesn't work inside Relative layouts

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `android:weightSum="1.0"` in your first LinearLayout (the one which contain the view with a weight)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: it did use to be like that. i'll try

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like `LinearLayout` as parent element and use `layout_weight` inside their `child element` you might get the desired result. But if you have `ScrollView` as main parent and use `layout_weight` attribute inside one of its `child element` it might not prove to be a good result. Bcs, `ScrollView` is endless and it will end only where its child element gets finished. So, obviously if you use `weight` attribute inside that `Android` may not be able to figure out actually where you want to end the `scroll` and misbehave.

So, try to keep the `LinearLayout` which contains `TextView`(with Got It text) at the bottom of main layout. Remove that `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` and paste it outside the `ScrollView` so that it will be there at the bottom irespective of scroll.

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/whyResgisterHeaderText"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="WHY REGISTER?"
                style="@style/textOnBg"
                android:textAllCaps="true" 
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:font_type="varela"/>

            <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/whyResgisterBodyText"
                style="@style/textOnBg"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="first line\nsecond line\nthird line\nforth line"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_why" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gotItAction"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/goItText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Got it"
            android:textColor="#00bcfe"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```